# Angularjs - $compile element on click variable is not compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I would like to compile element oc click with new variable but the after the first click variable shows up in curly brackets {{variable}} -> see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/u1DxkDVaKD9sCMFUE7pB)

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.directive('tester',function($compile){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'fruits.html',
    replace:true,
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
      elem.bind("click", function(e){
        scope.fruit = 'apple';

        var template = "<p>{{fruit}}</p>";
          elem.append(template);
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
 elem.append(template);
 $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
```

As of now you are compiling first and then appending.
Swap the lines and it'll work.

Comment: I've tried this one before and unfortunately it doesn't work.